# Similar to PipelineCopyAllFilesToOneFolderForMsdeployDependsOn for UWP packaging

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, msbuild, msbuild-task, msix

As you can see in [Web Deployment Tool (MSDeploy) : Build Package including extra files or excluding specific files](http://sedodream.com/2010/05/01/WebDeploymentToolMSDeployBuildPackageIncludingExtraFilesOrExcludingSpecificFiles.aspx) and [Adding Custom Files to an MSDeploy Package](https://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2013/03/08/adding-custom-files-to-an-msdeploy-package.aspx/) msbuild desired target has property event that name is `PipelineCopyAllFilesToOneFolderForMsdeployDependsOn` for handling copy desired files into process.

I need something similar for UWP, to add custom file copy to `AppX` folder during packaging and `f5 click` in Visual Studio in `.csproj` file.

Comment: You might need to ask this in https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Why? I do not need extra feature or I do not report a bug, I need to know How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many working I found solution, AppX Packaging is coordinate from `Microsoft.AppxPackage.Targets` that exists in `Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\AppxPackage` and all important target for packaging and running (f5 in Visual Studio) exists here.

As you can see in this file, Microsoft create some blank target between important target in build and packaging pipeline, so you can use override these blank targets very cleanly to control procedure of building and packaging AppX, for example you can override blow targets

```
      <!-- Override to specify actions to happen before generating project PRI file. -->
      <Target Name="BeforeGenerateProjectPriFile" />
```

or

```
      <!-- Override to specify actions to happen after generating project PRI file. -->
      <Target Name="AfterGenerateProjectPriFile" />
```

or ...

So for adding custom files into packaging I override `BeforeGenerateProjectPriFile` target and for adding file, I used `PackagingOutputs` `ItemGroup` for adding my file like below

```
  <Target Name="BeforeGenerateProjectPriFile">
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackagingOutputs Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).exe.config">
        <OutputGroup>ContentFilesProjectOutputGroup</OutputGroup>
        <TargetPath>$(AssemblyName).exe.config</TargetPath>
        <ProjectName>$(ProjectName)</ProjectName>
      </PackagingOutputs>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

If you want this approach in practice, I used this technique in [linphone-windows10](https://github.com/BSVN/linphone-windows10)